# MongoDB - Document with different type of value

Tags: mongodb

I'm very new to MongoDB, i tell you sorry for this question but i have a problem to understand how to create a document that can contain a value with different "type:

My document can contain data like this:

```
// Example ONE
{
    "customer" : "aCustomer",
    "type": "TYPE_ONE",
    "value":    "Value here"
}

// Example TWO
{
    "customer": "aCustomer",
    "type": "TYPE_TWO",
    "value": {
        "parameter1": "value for parameter one",
        "parameter2": "value for parameter two"
    }
}

// Example THREE
{
    "customer": "aCustomer",
    "type": "TYPE_THREE",
    "value": {
        "anotherParameter": "another value",
        {
            "someParameter": "value for some parameter",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Customer field will be even present, the type can be different (TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO and so on), based on the TYPE the value can be a string, an object, an array etc.

Looking this example, i should create three kind of collections (one for type) or the same collection (for example, a collection named "measurements") can contain differend kind of value on the field "value" ?

Trying some insert in my DB instance i dont get any error (i'm able to insert object, string and array on property value), but i would like to know if is the correct way...

I come from RDBMS, i'm a bit confused right now.. thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: One of the advantages of MongoDB is that you can store different "types" in the same field, even in the same collection. There is no fixed schema and if your application can handle different types, there is no real reason to use different collections.

Comment: Right now i dont need to create index on "value" field, i will need to create index on the other two fields yes (customer and type), but the "value" is just a value and dont need to be indexed..... for now... In future, i can create index on fields like "value" that can store different kind of data ?

Comment: You can have multiple indices like "value" and "value.parameter1". "value" will only work on documents that store normal values/arrays, "value.parameter1" will index documents that have nested objects with key parameter1. Well at least as far as I know.

Comment: The last comment was not correct. Indexing "value" will also give you an index on nested documents, but you have to specify the whole document in your search query (including the correct order). If you want to query specific sub-fields with the dot notation, you have to use multi-key indices like "value.parameter1"

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer here https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/use-cases/product-catalog

> MongoDB's dynamic schema means that each need not conform to the same schema.

Comment: Above link doesn't work anymore.